# rpm-ostree install fails - error: The following base packages would be replaced

Tags: centos7

I'm hitting the following on CentOS Atomic 7

```
rpm-ostree install open-vm-tools
Checking out tree 0bf6200... done

Downloading metadata: [===========================================================================================================] 100%
Resolving dependencies... failed
error: The following base packages would be replaced: pciutils-libs-3.5.1-1.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

That means that you can't install the package because it depends on a newer  version of pcilibs-utils than is in your base ostree.  You'll need to get a new base ostree in order to install that additional package.